# Не изменяется переменная внутри класса сеттером, выдаётся первоначальное значение. Как исправить?

Tags: python

```
class User:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__health = 100
        self.__damage = 10

    @property
    def health(self):
        return self.__health

    @property
    def damage(self):
        return self.__damage

    @health.setter
    def health1(self):
        self.__health -= self.damage

test = User()
print(test.health1)
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на ruSO! Отформатируйте пожалуйста блок кода, отредактируйте вопрос используя кнопку `Править` под вопросом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    @health.setter
    def health1(self):
        self.__health -= self.damage
```

у сеттера имя должно совпадать с именем геттера, и должен быть второй параметр, через который придет новое значение при присваивании через `test.health = new_health`. Т.е. должно быть так:

```
    @health.setter
    def health(self, value):
        self.__health = value
```

Сеттеры предназначены именно для установки нового значения, они вызываются при присваивании нового значения по их имени, а не просто при их "упоминании" (как у вас в коде `print(test.health1)`).

Если нужно выполнить действие, а не передать новое значение, то вам нужен просто обычный метод, а не проперти. Например, ниже в коде я добавил метод `hit_myself`, который уменьшает значение `health` на значение `damage`:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__health = 100
        self.__damage = 10

    @property
    def health(self):
        return self.__health

    @health.setter
    def health(self, value):
        self.__health = value

    @property
    def damage(self):
        return self.__damage

    def hit_myself(self):
        self.health -= self.damage


test = User()
print(test.health)
test.hit_myself()
print(test.health)
```

Вывод:

```
100
90
```

Comment: большое спасибо, вы мне действительно помогли разобраться